# Reports with daily, weekly, monthly and yearly basis

Tags: mysql, report

I am making reports with daily, weekly, monthly and yearly basis. All the data will come from one table which is this:
**table name:** reservation

```
reservation_id  firstname   lastname    arrival     departure   numNights   payable     downPayment balance 
216             Liam        Ree         22/03/2016  31/03/2016  9           30600.00    9180.00     21420.00 
215             Yuu         Yuu         08/03/2016  19/03/2016  11          69300.00    20790.00    48510.00
214             Kim         Kim         01/03/2016  04/03/2016  3           15300.00    4590.00     10710.00 
213             Jan         Jan         29/02/2016  02/03/2016  4           20400.00    6120.00     14280.00 
211             Wesley      Lin         17/02/2016  19/02/2016  2           6800.00     2040.00     4760.00 
212             Jan         Jan         23/02/2016  26/02/2016  3           20700.00    6210.00     14490.00 
218             Ram         Ram         03/01/2017  07/01/2017  4           20400.00    6120.00     14280.00
```

My query for **daily:**

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`arrival`, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) AS 'year',
COUNT(reservation_id) AS 'reservations',
SUM(payable) AS 'total'
FROM `reservation`
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`arrival`, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'))
ORDER BY YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`arrival`, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) ASC
```

Here's the result of the query(**daily**):

```
 Day    Reservations    Total   
NULL    4               78500.00
1       1               20400.00
3       2               84600.00
```

I don't get why the first row/result is null, plus that is not the desired output, plus the result is somewhat not right based on the data in the reservation table. What I want to see is something like the reservation within this day (current day) and the total (payable) for this day (current day alone).

For **weekly report**:

```
SELECT FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) 
-MOD(TO_DAYS(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) -1, 7)) AS week,
SUM(payable) AS total, COUNT(*) AS reservations FROM reservation GROUP BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) 
-MOD(TO_DAYS(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) -1, 7))
ORDER BY FROM_DAYS(TO_DAYS(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'))
-MOD(TO_DAYS(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) -1, 7))
```

**result:**

```
week        total       reservations    
NULL        78500.00    4
2016-01-03  15300.00    1
2016-07-31  69300.00    1
2017-02-26  20400.00    1
```

Then again this is not what should be. **The desired result** should be:

```
week    reservations    total
week 1  4               10000.00
week 2  3               2000.00
week 3  2               100.00
week 4  5               25000.00
```

It should show all the weeks within a month, weeks with or without reservation.

For **monthly report** query:

```
SELECT count(reservation_id) AS reservations,
YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) AS 'year',
MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) AS 'month',
SUM(payable) AS 'total'
FROM `reservation` 
 GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')),
MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) 
ORDER BY YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) ASC,
MONTH(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(arrival, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) ASC
```

here's the result of the query**(monthly)**:

```
reservations    year    month   total   
4               NULL    NULL    78500.00
1               2016    1       15300.00
1               2016    8       69300.00
1               2017    3       20400.00
```

again, the result there's null in first row :( i dont even know why. and the **desired result** should be:

```
reservations    year    month     total     
1               2016    january   1000.00
0               2016    april     00.00
0               2016    january   1000.00
-----------up to december----------------
1               2016    december  1000.00
```

It will also display the months without reservation (which is not included in the reservation table).

And now for **yearly report**:

```
SELECT YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`arrival`, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) AS 'year',
COUNT(reservation_id) AS 'reservations',
SUM(payable) AS 'total'
FROM `reservation`
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`arrival`, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s'))
ORDER BY YEAR(DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`arrival`, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%s')) ASC
```

**query result:**

```
 year   reservations    total   
NULL    4               78500.00
2016    2               84600.00
2017    1               20400.00
```

Result above seems ok. Only the null part and the reservation with 4 and 2 are both 2016. I do not know why the first row is null and the it did not group the data that belongs to year 2016 (4 and 2).

Note: arrival column is in varchar format because the arrival and departure comes from user input using a datepicker(js). I used the str_to_date and date_format to format the arrival in timestamp like format.

Comment: Please store dates as dates. And then get back to us.

Comment: im getting 00/00/00 values when i changed from varchar to date or even datetime datatype

Answer (score 0):

If the date, time, or datetime value extracted from str is illegal, STR_TO_DATE() will return NULL and produce a warning. Have you checked your data for consistency? Is MySQL giving any warnings?

Use SHOW WARNINGS statement to enable warnings.